# Prove that if $Y$ is hausdorff then $Y^X$ is it too when it is equipped with open-compact topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

So in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542926/736008) question is asked to show that if $Y$ is an Hausdorff space then for any other space $X$ the subset of continuous function $\mathcal C(X,Y)$ of $Y^X$ is Hausdorff but I think that really just $Y^X$ is it too: indeed it seem to me that [Brian Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542943/736008) do not use continuity, right? So is really $Y^X$ Hausdorff when $Y$ is it? Could someone explain if Brian Scott's answer use continuity?

Comment: Can you remind us what $Y^X$ is?

Comment: The notation $Y^{X}$ for two sets $X$ and $Y$ usually denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$. (The motivation for this notation is that for finite sets $\vert Y^{X}\vert=\vert Y\vert^{\vert X\vert}$).

Comment: Well, the open-compact topology on $C(X,Y)$ uses the fact that elements of this set are *continuous* functions (by definition). Since the answer by Brian Scott uses the subbasis of this specific topology, does this not necessarily uses continuity?

Comment: @G.Blaickner Well really open compact topology is defined in $Y^X$ and Brian Scott use subbasis elements of $Y^X$ as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603375/736008) where is defined open-compact topology: is this false?

Comment: For a locally compact space $X$, the compact-open topology $C_\mathrm{co}(X,-)$ is uniquely defined by being the right adjoint to $-\times X$ (therefore being the internal hom). I currently don't know how, but maybe this could be useful for an elegant answer, since when using this adjunction, the space $Y$ (from which the seperation axiom is inherited) will be isolated on the right side: $C(A,C_\mathrm{co}(X,Y))\cong C(A\times X,Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the compact-open topology on the whole set $Y^X$, simply by using the family $\{M(C,U):C$ compact, $U$ open$\}$ as a subbase, where $M(C,U)=\{f:f[C]\subseteq U\}$.
It contains the product topology, which has $\{M(\{x\},U):x\in X$, $U$ open$\}$ as a subbase, so it is Hausdorff if $Y$ is.
For stronger properties, like regularity and complete regularity, you need to work in $C(X,Y)$ because there you use compactness of $f[C]$ all the time.

Comment: Okay, all clear now: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!! :-)

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4608268/736008) your assistance, please?